# Subscribe to changes on property of component in Angular 2 for debounced auto saving?

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

Say I have the following Angular 2 component, where `foo` is an object not bound to a form, and not coming from an `Input()`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    templateUrl: '/angular/views/foo.template.html',
    directives: [ContentEditableDirective, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FooService]
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    public foo: Foo = new Foo();

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,
        private router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.fooService.getFoo(id).subscribe(
            foo => {
                this.foo = foo;

                // I have this.foo, we should watch for changes here.

                Observable. // ???
                    .debounceTime(1000)
                    .subscribe(input => fooService.autoSave(this.foo));
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

How can I subscribe to changes to the `Foo` object, and send it up to my server?

Every example I have seen so far involves either having `foo` come off of an `Input()`, or being bound to a form. I just want to watch a plain old Javascript object for changes and react to that.

### Update

I have tried once again, and have been able to debounce an internal *primitive* property on a component [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l47WjeXEOOk9eVMAc8Fj?p=preview).

**But, I have been unable to make this work with a complex object that has properties of its own ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HMJz6UWeZIBovMkXlR01?p=preview))**; as the setter in the provided plnkr is not called by `ngModel` when it updates the property of the `foo` object.

A correct answer will demonstrate this working with a complex object.

### Update 2

[I believe I have it working with a complex object](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vmrz8PUDRQxLkkbggn6R?p=preview); but one must ensure the object is immutable and that you have setters for each property, which is kind of a letdown. It also appears to require the splitting of `[(ngModel)]` into `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` so you can specify custom setter logic.

You could theoretically abstract the functionality to a state service, but I'd like to see if the amount of boilerplate can be stripped down further. Creating new objects each time you would like a state change is kind of frustrating.

Comment: using the angular2 zone may help here, you can hook into the zone and call your code every time a new async operation is performed, actually async operations like events, https, timeouts and so. This is exactly when angular2 runs change detection under the assumptions that these async operations can change properties.
Good entry point for this would be: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html  , Tell me it this help or if you need any more details

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I appear to have partially solved this for simple & complex objects. If one has no need for an entire change detector, you can implement this easily with just:

- A subject and an observable on your component.
- A getter and a setter for the tracked property on your component.

Below is a very minimal example of how one could accomplish this.

### Component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="foo"  />
      <div>current Foo: {{ foo }}</div>
      <div>debounced Foo: {{ debouncedFoo }}</div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  private _foo: any;
  debouncedFoo: any;
  fooSubject : Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(this._foo);
  fooStream : Observable<any> = this.fooSubject.asObservable();

  get foo() {
      return this._foo;
  });

  set foo(value:any) {
    this._foo = value;
    this.fooSubject.next(value);
  });

  constructor() {
    // Manipulate your subscription stream here
    this.subscription = this.fooStream
      .debounceTime(2000)
      .subscribe(
        value => {
          this.debouncedFoo = value;
      });
  }
}
```

### Example

http://plnkr.co/edit/HMJz6UWeZIBovMkXlR01?p=preview

Of course, realistically the component should have no knowledge of the subject or observable, so extract them to a service as you please.

### Downsides

This example only works with primitives. If you would like it to work with objects, you need custom setter logic for each property, and remember to create new objects each time you alter a property of that object.

Comment: I really like this answer! +1 for using get/set - didn't think of that, hence my seperate class.

Answer (score 3):

@vjawala is very close :)

If you want to track input (annotated with `@Input`) properties use `OnChanges`:

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes['foo']){
        triggerAutoSave();
    }
  }
```

If you want to track key/value object, then implement `DoCheck` listener and use `KeyValueDiffer`, example is provided in angular docs.

It might be much more efficient/simple to subscribe directly to change/input (most likely both) events:

```
<form (input)="triggerAutoSave()" (change)="triggerAutoSave()">
   <input>
   <input>
   <input>
</form>
```

Debounce is relatively easy with RxJS:

```
triggerAutoSave(){
     subject.next(this.foo);
}

subject.debounceTime(500).subscribe(...);
```

If you are saving via http then `exhaustMap` might help.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use the `ngDoCheck()` function? Something like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    templateUrl: '/angular/views/foo.template.html',
    directives: [ContentEditableDirective, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FooService]
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
    public foo: Foo = new Foo();

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,
        private router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.foo = this.fooService.getFoo(id);
    }
    ngDoCheck() {
        fooService.autoSave(this.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how the autosave functionality would work and give me access to an observable stream that I could manipulate?

Comment: Inside the fooService you could do whatever you want with the value that's saved (before saving it). Unless you mean something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I just came up with. It probably needs a little polishing, but it works well regardless.

> Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kbTMSa0lPfiqESod3Z3q?p=preview) for example usage

---

```
export class ChangeTracker {
  private _object: any;
  private _objectRetriever: () => any;
  private _objectSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  private _onChange: (obj: any) => void;
  private _fnCompare: (a: any, b: any) => boolean;

  constructor(objRetriever: () => any, 
              onChange: (obj: any) => void, 
              fnCompare?: (a: any, b: any) => boolean) {

    this._object = objRetriever();
    this._objectRetriever = objRetriever;
    this._onChange = onChange;
    this._fnCompare = fnCompare ? fnCompare : this.defaultComparer;

    this._objectSubject
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this._onChange(data);
      });

    setInterval(() => this.detectChanges(), 500);
  }

  private defaultComparer(a: any, b: any) {
    return JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b);
  }

  private detectChanges() {
    let currentObject = this._objectRetriever();

    if (!this._fnCompare(this._object, currentObject)) {
      this._object = currentObject;

      this._objectSubject.next(currentObject);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage in your code sample:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    templateUrl: '/angular/views/foo.template.html',
    directives: [ContentEditableDirective, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FooService]
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    public foo: Foo = new Foo();

    constructor(
        private fooService: FooService,
        private route : ActivatedRoute,
        private router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.fooService.getFoo(id).subscribe(
            foo => {
                this.foo = foo;

                /* just create a new ChangeTracker with a reference
                 * to the local foo variable and define the action to be
                 * taken on a detected change
                 */
                new ChangeTracker(
                    () => this.foo, 
                    (value) => {
                        this.fooService.autoSave(value);
                    }
                );
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very promising, thank you. When I have some spare time I will look into this tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm. `setInterval(() => this.detectChanges(), 500);` So really you're just manually doing lots of work every half second? Seems kind of dirty.

Comment: Yes, but Angular's change detection does the same, even more often - detecting changes is not black magic. If you have more variables you want to track you could consider putting change detection into a service which is running through an array of them periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of streams in angular2.
I had same requirement as such, I had implemented that using streams in a service as following:

**user.service.ts**

```
selectedUserInstance:user = new User();

// Observable selectUser source
private selectUserSource = new Subject<any>();
// Observable selectUser stream
selectUser$ = this.selectUserSource.asObservable();

// service command
selectUser(user:User) {
    //console.log(user);
    this.selectedUserInstance=user;    
    this.selectUserSource.next(this.selectedUserInstance);
}
```

**inside component**

```
this.subscription = this.userService.selectUser$.subscribe(
  selectedUser => {
    this.selectedUser = selectedUser;
    console.log("In component : " + this.selectedUser.name);
  });
```