# How handle changes of standard html attributes in angular2 component?

Tags: angular

Problem is I should handle standard attributes change in angular2 component, disabled for example.
@Attribute gives us static value, also tried adding @Input disabled and setter for property, but it do not used in that case I think, can't catch a breakpoint inside.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "handle"? Like an event firing when the value of an attribute changes?

Comment: @rinukkusu yes, something like that, I need to make some internal action on change

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38316181/1961059